# why does the user always get a return true in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop, return, population

```
  public boolean askQuestion(ArrayList < Application.Country > countries) {
      int randomNumber = this.getRandomPositionList(countries.size());
      Application.Country country1 = countries.get(randomNumber);
      int randomNumber1 = this.getRandomPositionList(countries.size());
      Application.Country country2 = countries.get(randomNumber1);
      System.out.println("Which country has a larger population? ");
      System.out.println("a) " + country1.name);
      System.out.println("b) " + country2.name);
      String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
      while (!userInput.matches("[a-b]")) {
          System.out.println("Please enter an a or b");
          userInput = scanner.nextLine();
          if (userInput.matches("a")) {
              boolean a = country1.population > country2.population;
            } else {
              return false;
          }
          if (userInput.matches("b")) {
              boolean b = country1.population > country2.population;
            } else {
              return false;
          }
     }
      return true;
  }
```

I want to ask from the user what the bigger population is from two random countries in a quiz. Every time the user uses an a or b to fill the answers in, it gets a true in return. I don't know how to fix it. I also used the return statement in the if and else.

Comment: You don't return a or b. You just assign to them then ignore them and return true.

Comment: You need to move the `matches("a")` and `matches("b")` checks out of the while loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can u be a bit more precise. Im a beginner. Can you share the code?

Comment: You could replace `boolean a = country1.population > country2.population;` with `return (country1.population > country2.population);` if that condition is what you're supposed to return.

Comment: You're currently only checking for a or b if the first input was incorrect. You need to move those checks out of the while loop so they happen after the while loop condition evaluates to false.

Comment: I cant move the boolean condition out of the loop: it says the loop is broken

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed code. Your code had a logic flaw in it and it always returned true no matter what.

You were also checking for the condition in the while loop, which would have never run if the user inputted `a` or `b` the first time.

```
public boolean askQuestion(ArrayList < Application.Country > countries) {
      int randomNumber = this.getRandomPositionList(countries.size());
      Application.Country country1 = countries.get(randomNumber);
      int randomNumber1 = this.getRandomPositionList(countries.size());
      Application.Country country2 = countries.get(randomNumber1);
      System.out.println("Which country has a larger population? ");
      System.out.println("a) " + country1.name);
      System.out.println("b) " + country2.name);
      String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
      while (!userInput.matches("[a-b]")) {
          System.out.println("Please enter an a or b");
          userInput = scanner.nextLine();
     }
     String answer = (country1.population > country2.population) ? "a" : "b";
     if (userInput.matches(answer)) {
         return true;
     } 
     return false;
 }
```